# How do I use C# to post to this form grammatically?

Tags: c#, ajax, forms, web

I am trying to check my gift card balance, (I have many) on the following website and I want to automate via a C# program.

https://www.fivebackgift.com/

It is form1 in the source code im interested in. This is my code:

```
class Program
{


    public static string HttpPost(string url, params object[] postData)
    {
        StringBuilder post = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < postData.Length; i += 2)
            post.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}={2}", i == 0 ? "" : "&", postData[i], postData[i + 1]));
        return HttpPost(url, post.ToString());
    }
    public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData)
    {
        postData = postData.Replace("\r\n", "");
        try
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
            byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = send.Length;

            Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
            sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
            sout.Flush();
            sout.Close();

            WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
            string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return returnvalue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("POST Error on {0}\n  {1}", url, ex.Message);
            return "";
        }


    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        HttpPost("https://www.fivebackgift.com/Card/_Login?returnUrl=Transactions", 
            "CardNumber", "CREDIT NUMBER",
            "ExpirationMonth", "MONTH",
            "ExpirationYear", "YEAR",
            "SecurityCode", "CODE");
    }
}
```

I just want to see if the website would give me a response. The following error is what I get:

```
POST Error on https://www.fivebackgift.com/Card/_Login?returnUrl=Transactions
  The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

How do I figure out what the real URL should be?

Comment: See if the website has an API. Other than that, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Are your parameters from static main correct?. I mean you are expecting your post method to get one string for url and one array of object for postData, while you are currently sending url as string that is correct but you aren't sending object array to that method from static main whereas you are sending individual strings. Look your main method.